# Python 3.x version. Want to input a function

Tags: python-3.x

my code is :

```
from sympy import symbols

x = symbols ('x')

def f(x):
    y = input("what is your function?")
    return y
print (f(1))
```

But if I put x**2 + 3 as an input and run the code then it prints x**2 +3
Why this happens?

I think the builtin function input does not take 'x' as a variable.

How can I fix it?

Comment: But the brackets do not even match?

Comment: That's just a typo error. I edited

Comment: You get a string with input, return it and print it. I assume you want the input to be parsed and treated as a mathematical function?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted. But how can I return it to a mathematical thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to use a variable name in expression, you cannot directly use `ast.litteral_eval` which is a secure alternative to (the evil) `eval`.

At least you can try to remove builtins from the global context:

```
def f(x):
    y = input("Function:")
    return eval(y, {'__builtins__': {}}, {'x': x})
```

But beware, even with builtins removed [eval may not be safe](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

You could also use the variant proposed by Steven:

```
def g(**args):
    y = input("Function:")
    return eval(y, {'__builtins__': {}}, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get an expression formatted with any arguments that match. Although it doesn't work if you have for example `xs` and `x` as variables since `x` will replace `x` in `xs` since I didn't handle that in this example, so be aware of that.

```
def get_exp(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs) # left in to show how kwargs looks
    inp = input('--> ')
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        inp = inp.replace(k, str(v))
    return inp
```

---

```
# Use
>>> exp = get_exp(x = 5, y = 10)
{'x': 5, 'y': 10}
--> x ** 5 + (y - 2)
>>> exp
'5 ** 5 + (10 - 2)'
>>> exp = get_exp(x = 5, y = 10)
{'x': 5, 'y': 10}
--> z + x
>>> exp
'z + 5'
```

As for evaluating the expression look to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4831822) on safely evaluating input using `ast` module or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371789/4831822) for `pyparsing`.

If you want to use the `sympy` module then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556473/4831822) has an example on use. However be aware the `sympy` isn't considered safe.